# How can i write a conditional statement with Text as its values?

Tags: firebase, flutter, if-statement, dart, google-cloud-firestore

Firstly, I created some text values

```
  Text gamecon1 = Text('1v1 Box Fight');
  Text gamecon1duo = Text('1v1 Duos');
  Text gamecon2 = Text('2v2 Box Fight');
  Text gamecon2sq = Text('2v2 Squads');
  Text gamecon3 = Text('3v3 Box Fight');
  Text gamecon4 = Text('4v4 Box Fight');
```

Then i queried a document field from firestore and wrote a conditional statement

```
  Text((() {
                                          if (tourneyDetails['tourneyprizes'] ==
                                              gamecon1) {
                                            return multiplier = 8;
                                          } else if (tourneyDetails[
                                                  'tourneyprizes'] ==
                                              gamecon1duo) {
                                            return multiplier = 5;
String calculator = (int.parse(
                                                      tourneyDetails[
                                                          'tourneycost']) *
                                                  multiplier)
                                              .toString();
                                          String calculatordivide =
                                              (double.parse(calculator) / 100.0)
                                                  .toString();
                                          String calculatorpercentage =
                                              (double.parse(calculatordivide) *
                                                      20)
                                                  .toString();
                                          String calculatorfinal =
                                              (double.parse(calculator) -
                                                      double.parse(
                                                          calculatorpercentage))
                                                  .toString();

                                          return calculatorfinal;
```

What i am trying to accomplish is, if the document field is equal to one the text values, then it should run the calculation and return the value.
but this doesn't work.
After some troubleshooting, i realised that even when the text value is the same as the document field queried, flutter still doesn't recognise it.
If you need more context feel free to comment. Thanks

Comment: Please show your definition of tourneyDetails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing what the type definition of tourneyDetails is I cannot be sure but I suspect that you are trying to compare a String (in tourneyDetails) with a Text widget. If so, they will never equate. You should be defining your strings as constants eg. const gamecon1 = '1v1 Box Fight'; then the comparison should equate.

Answer (score 1):

Text() is a widget. You want to compare Strings.
`if (tourneyDetails['tourneyprizes'] == gamecon1.data)`
or
`define String gamecon1 = 'gamecon1'` and tourneyDetails must also be an array of Strings.